# promise async code don't work puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    var urls = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.firefox.com'];
    await Promise.all(urls.map(async (url) => {
        await page.goto(url, { timeout: 0, waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
        console.log(page.url());
    }))
    await browser.close();
});
```

this code returns 2 times the last url of array, why?

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=firefox-com
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=firefox-com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you pass to `map` gets run on each URL **in parallel**.

You are only remote controlling **one browser**.

So you tell it to `goto` one page, then you `await` a response which lets the next function be picked it. It tells the browser to go to a *different* page, which cancels the attempt to go to the first page. When it arrives at that page, both promises get the "I've arrived!" message and pick up to read the data.

You need to loop over your URLs and run them in **sequence** instead of in parallel.

Comment: One might have expected though that the promise from the first `page.goto` would get rejected once it is cancelled by the second call

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Quentin explains **why** this happens and in addition I would like to add  a code sample how you can do it in sequence. In the following example browser will visit the pages one after another:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.firefox.com'];

    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        await page.goto(urls[i], {timeout: 0, waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
        console.log(page.url());
    }

    await browser.close();
});
```

If you want to visit the pages concurrently you can open two pages in the browser and do something like this, which will end up faster than the previous example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {

    let urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.firefox.com'];
    await Promise.all(urls.map((url) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            // Open new page for each url
            let page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(url, {timeout: 0, waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
            console.log(page.url());
            resolve();
        });
    }));

    await browser.close();
});
```